# tensorflow run time stable on CPU, but goes up on GPU

Tags: python, performance, tensorflow, gpu, slowdown

I have a problem where I'm timing how long each batch takes to run. When it's run on CPU, the time takes to run iteration is 10X the GPU initially but it's consistent, but when I run on GPU, the time keeps going up. Here is a sample code:

```py
def feedward_model(graph, input_x_placeholder):
    with graph.as_default():
       # nn_layer takes input nodes and output y    
       y = nn_layer(input_x_placeholder)
       return y
def train_model(graph, y_true_placeholder, predicted_y):
    with graph.as_default():
        cross_entropy = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(labels=y_true_placeholder, logits=predicted_y)
        train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cross_entropy)
        return train_step, cross_entropy

def timeit(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kw):
        ts = time()
        result = f(*args, **kw)
        te = time()
        delta = te-ts
        print('func:%r took: %2.4f sec' %(f.__name__, delta))
        return result
    return wrap
```

```py
g = tf.Graph()

with g.as_default():
   # placeholder block
   train_x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
   train_y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)

def feed_dict():
   # data batching block, x and y will be generated in batches:
    x = np.array() 
    y = np.array()
    return {train_x: x, train_y: y}

with tf.Session(graph=g, config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True, log_device_placement=True)) as sess:
    run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
    run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()

    with graph.as_default():
        pred_y = feedforward_model(graph, train_x)    
        train_step, cross_entropy = train_model(graph, train_y, pred_y)

    @timeit
    def train_run():
       _, loss = session.run([train_step, cross_entropy], feed_dict=feed_dict(), options=run_options, run_metadata=run_metadata)

    for i in range(1000):
        train_run()
```

In the stdout i get the time takes to run each iteration[image]

I removed all possible stage where it has to communicate back to CPU, i.e. logging, tf.summary. I cannot think of any reason the same graph works consistent with CPU, but run time starts going up ~200 iterations on GPU..

#### [UPDATE]

I figured out the problem .. The final logging I didn't remove is

```
run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
```

Now that I removed these two from `session.run`, the time to run each iteration on GPU has stabled. I suppose every time the session.run is called, the `FULL_TRACE` gets longer, thus time goes up linearly. But why would the GPU run time only start going up around 200? and why it didn't affect runs on CPU?